# Regular Expression that does not match a given sequence

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I need a regular expression that matches this text description:

```
"any sequence that is not an F (upper case only) followed by a run of 1 or more digits (0-9)".
```

This needs to go as input to Java's Scanner.useDelimiter().

Suppose the input line is this:

```
F8 has pretty solid open source cred: in F12 he founded F25, he was the F44 of F1 and the F121, and he helped pave the way for F99.
```

The tokenizer class Scanner should then retrieve F8, F12, F25, F44, F1, F121 and F99 for me.

Alternately, does Java allow negating a given regex?

Comment: Instead of _splitting_ by the inverse, it is often easier to _match_ the expression itself, i.e. something like `F\d+`

Comment: @tobias_k Indeed.  See the answer by Avinash Raj below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Pattern and Matcher classes to fetch only the chars you want.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\bF\\d+").matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```